# Send data to Web Api from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In Web Api I have a simple method that takes model `Student`:

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void CreateStudent([FromBody]Student student)
{
    db.Students.Add(student);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Method of my MVC application:

```
public void Form(string Name, string Surname, string Qualification, string Specialty, double Rating)
{
    Student student = new Student
    {
        Name = Name,
        Surname = Surname,
        Qualification = Qualification,
        Specialty = Specialty,
        Rating = Rating
    };

    //Here I must send student object to Web Api with ulr "http://localhost:2640/api/values"
}
```

And I want to send from my MVC application object Student to Web Api, but I dont know how I can do it. What I must to do?

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials available regarding MVC and WebAPI.  What have you tried?  Can you post your code?

Comment: Is your Web API hosted in the same site with your MVC?

Comment: I posted my code. Im trying, but i cant to do it.                                                        Web Api - 1 projekt                                                                                              MVC app - 2 projekt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a Web API Controller like this:

```
public class StudentsController : ApiController {
    // POST api/students
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Student student) {
        db.Students.Add(student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

located at the following endpoint

```
http://localhost:2640/api/students
```

You can use `HttpClient` to communicate with the WebApi from your MVC controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Form(string Name, string Surname, string Qualification, string Specialty, double Rating) {

    Student student = new Student {
        Name = Name,
        Surname = Surname,
        Qualification = Qualification,
        Specialty = Specialty,
        Rating = Rating
    };

    // Here I must send student object to Web Api
    // URL: "http://localhost:2640/api/students"
    var client = new HttpClient();
    car endpoint = "http://localhost:2640/api/students";
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(endpoint, student);
    if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(student);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't working, i don't have any error, but i cheked response.IsSuccessStatusCode and its False

Comment: What doesn't work? What did you use form the answer?

Comment: I used this method but it is not saved data to my web api db.

Comment: make sure the URIs are correctly matched to your Web API. This is just an example. Debug your code and step through to make sure that the web api is actually being called.

Comment: All works, big thanks. Error was here    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/students", student); , must be full name of web api that looks var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:2640/api/students", student);